# Python class derived from built-in type won't construct: TypeError: type() takes at most X arguments (Y given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, initialization

Python 2.7, Windows7x64.

The code. Note that `class ImmedVal` derives from built-in type `long`.

```
class Immediate(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value, loc):
        object.__init__(self)
        self.value = value
        self.loc = loc
        self.name = name

class ImmedVal(long, Immediate):
    def __init__(self, name, value, loc):
        long.__init__(self, value)
        Immediate.__init__(self, name, value, loc)
```

But attempts to instantiate ImmedVal...

```
x = ImmedVal('hello', 33, 7)
```

... don't work:

> TypeError: long() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

All different combinations of numbers/types of parameters on construction don't work.

P.S.: I'm doing this so referencing it returns the value, so I can use it as such:

```
eval('x + 1', { 'x' : x })
```

Comment: I'm confused about your use-case here... `eval` will return a value if `X` is a regular `long`, why do you need a subclass?

Comment: I want x to return its long value when used undecorated in an expression, but I want the object to carry the extra fields for other uses. HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That built-in type is immutable.**  That changes the game, and I need the [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) operator as such:

```
class ImmedVal(long, Immediate):
    def __new__(cls, name, value, loc):
        return long.__new__(cls, value)

    def __init__(self, name, value, loc):
        long.__init__(self, value)
        Immediate.__init__(self, name, value, loc)
```

(Base `class Immediate` and `__init__` are unchanged from above.)

Construction, as above, now works as expected.